# Emacs: Cleaning up undo-tree

Tags: emacs, undo

I have noticed that in long editing sessions, calling `undo-tree` (C-x C-u) becomes slower and slower. I presume that the reason is that as the tree grows bigger it takes longer to parse it (as it keeps track of all my edits since I opened the file)

Is there any way to clear up the tree of undos on an open file? I have tried `C-x C-v` (`find-alternate-file`), but this re-opens the file which resets the cursor (and in modes like `org-mode`  collapses my lists)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Reset the `buffer-undo-tree` variable using `M-: (setq buffer-undo-tree nil)`. This discards the entire undo history of the buffer, as recorded by `undo-tree.el`.

This can also be made into a command and bound to a key with code like this:

```
(defun clear-undo-tree ()
  (interactive)
  (setq buffer-undo-tree nil))
(global-set-key [(control c) u] 'clear-undo-tree)
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know what the difference is between your answer and that of @npostavs?

Comment: One difference is that `undo-tree-discard-history` tries to prune history according to the variables `undo-limit`, `undo-strong-limit`, and `undo-outer-limit`, while my solution deletes the entire undo history. More importantly, `undo-tree-discard-history` is automatically invoked on every undo/redo/switch-branch operation, so obviously it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 4):

Note that this tip may be obsolete in recent undo-tree versions. From version 0.6 onwards, undo-tree uses "lazy tree-drawing" by default. This significantly speeds up visualization of large undo trees, by only drawing the visible portion (and extending it as necessary as you move around the tree). See the docstring for the `undo-tree-visualizer-lazy-drawing` variable for further details.

If you nonetheless want to discard the entire undo tree, manually setting `buffer-undo-tree` to `nil` is a good one-off solution. A longer-term solution is to reduce the values of `undo-limit`, `undo-strong-limit`, and `undo-outer-limit` to limit the undo tree size, by limiting how much undo history it stores before discarding older data.

Manually calling `undo-tree-discard-history` is pointless. It gets called automatically whenever you do anything undo-related.

Answer (score 3):

Occasionally I have to flush a buffer's undo-tree because I pasted some text that contained characters that cannot be displayed in the buffer/file's current encoding. So I found the function of @Amelio Vazquez-Reina very helpful. However, I don't want the function to be called by accident, so a added a confirmation prompt and a check that `buffer-undo-tree` really is a buffer local variable:

```
(defun clean-undo-tree ()
"Clear current buffer's undo-tree.
Undo-tree can cause problems with file encoding when characters
are inserted that cannot be represented using the files current
encoding. This is even the case when characters are only
temporarily inserted, e.g. pasted from another source and then
instantly deleted. In these situations it can be necessary to
clear the buffers undo-tree before saving the file."
  (interactive)
  (let ((buff (current-buffer)))
    (if (local-variable-p 'buffer-undo-tree)
        (if (y-or-n-p "Clear buffer-undo-tree? ")
            (progn
              (setq buffer-undo-tree nil)
              (message "Cleared undo-tree of buffer: %s" (buffer-name buff)))
          (message "Cancelled clearing undo-tree of buffer: %s" (buffer-name buff)))
      (error "Buffer %s has no local binding of `buffer-undo-tree'" (buffer-name buff)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can prune the tree instead of discarding the whole thing:

```
undo-tree-discard-history is a compiled Lisp function in
`undo-tree.el'.

(undo-tree-discard-history)

Discard undo history until we're within memory usage limits
set by `undo-limit', `undo-strong-limit' and `undo-outer-limit'.
```

Comment: What's the difference between calling the function `(undo-tree-discard-history)` and setting the variable `(buffer-undo-tree)` to `nil`? (as in @user4815162342 answer)

Comment: @user273158: reduce vs remove entirely as per user4815162342's comment. I hadn't noticed it was called every undo/redo. Presumably, you could lower the limits to make it more effective.